# Problemas con importacion en JS

Tags: javascript, modulos

Simplemente quiero importar una constante de otro modulo .js, pero no funciona y me da el error en consola:

```
index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///C:/Users/Ariana/Documents/Programacion-Web-BD/Dise%C3%B1o%20Web/HTML-CSS-JS/Udemy/Modulos/modulos.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
index.html:11 GET file:///C:/Users/Ariana/Documents/Programacion-Web-BD/Dise%C3%B1o%20Web/HTML-CSS-JS/Udemy/Modulos/modulos.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

Estos son los archivos:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Modulos</title>
        
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Modulos</h1>
        <script src="modulos.js"  type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS principal:

```
import {pi} from "./constantes.js";


console.log(pi);
```

JS desde donde se importa:

```
export const pi = Math.PI;
```

Comment: Podrías agregar cómo están dispuestos los archivos en la carpeta? Es decir, tienes todo junto en un mismo directorio?

Comment: Está todo en el mismo directorio, si.

Answer (score 1):

SI no me equivoco es porque estás accediendo al archivo HTML desde el navegador pero sin haber levantado un servidor local.

Prueba a levantar un servidor local, con eso debería de resolverse tu problema.

Una forma sencilla sería instalando el paquete Node http-server (https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), pero te sirve cualquier.